# Postgres Database Instance error

Tags: sql, postgresql, chown

I am trying to create a Postgresql database and add a user. First, I command:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

This should prompt me for my password, but it doesn't. Next, I command:

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

Which returns the error:

```
chown: postgres: illegal group name
```

Does this mean I have not created the directory? Why doesn't this work?

Thank you.

Comment: no. it means you don't have a group named `postgres` on your system. checking `/etc/group` will confirm that.

Comment: What instructions are you following - link? PostgreSQL version? Operating system and version?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's no `postgres` user or group to assign. Did you create them first?

Unless you're familiar with linux sysadmin I *strongly* recommend you [use existing packages for PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/download/).  See http://apt.postgresql.org/ (Ubuntu/Debian) and http://yum.postgresql.org (Fedora, RHEL, CentOS, etc). If you do that then all user/group creation, service registration, etc is done for you.

Comment: This is the tutorial I'm using. It doesn’t seem like they tell me at any point to make a group?

Comment: It's near the bottom of the page.